# SSIS - Date Coloumn to Variable Null and non-Null Values

Tags: sql, variables, ssis, null

Within an SSIS package I have a dataflow that extracts two coloumns from an access database a TaskID and a date

I store this in a ADO recordset and pass this to a For Each Loop Container

I am them attempting to assign each value pair to two variables "taskID" and "taskDate"
I then want to use thse two variables within a SQL Insert task that will then update the SQL database in several places with this information

The package works fine when im just pull out the taskID and insert that into sql but when i introduce the date it fails because the date can be NULL and most of the tasks are NULL but SSIS just keeps telling me that it cant put null into the variable, I tried having an Obejct variable which allowed nulls but then the package fails on adding the variable to the sql task as the variable in there is a DATE?

Thanks

Comment: Been watching this post. Sorry you don't have an answer. I might be able to figure it out, but SSIS is very visual and I'd have to sit in front of the actual screen/code for a while to do so. I'd guess that might be why no one else has posted anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a possible solution outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/mattm/archive/2007/06/15/optional-date-parameter.aspx) that uses a second variable and EvaluateAsExpression that may solve your problem.